# SymPy can print Exponentiation base and exponent?

Tags: sympy

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english!

I want

1.x : how to Determination of Exponentiation , Determination possible?

2.print : base=b ,exponent=n

WrongScript.py

```
from sympy import *
var('x y z a b n')
x=b**n
y=3**n
z=a
# output 1.---------------------------------
print("x=",x) # x= b**n,**
print("y=",y) # y= 3**n,**
print("z=",z) # z= a,   not **
# output 2.---------------------------------
print(MyBaseOut(x),MyExponentOut(x))  # b,n
print(MyBaseOut(y),MyExponentOut(y))  # 3,n

def MyBaseOut(p):
    #   ans=?
    return ans
def MyExponentOut(q):
    #   ans=?
    return ans
```

2018-11-26------------------------------

FullScript.py

```
from sympy import *
var('b n')
def MyBaseOut(p):
    return p.as_base_exp()[0]
def MyExponentOut(q):
    return q.as_base_exp()[1]
x=b**n
y=3**n
print(MyBaseOut(x),MyExponentOut(x))
print(MyBaseOut(y),MyExponentOut(y))
# b n
# 3 n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `is_Pow` will tell you if it has an exponent other than 1 and the method `as_base_exp()` will tell you what the base and exponent are -- select element 0 for the base and element 1 for the exponent:

```
>>> [(i.is_Pow, i.as_base_exp()) for i in (y,1/y,y**2,y**z)]
[(False, (y, 1)), (True, (y, -1)), (True, (y, 2)), (True, (y, z))]
```